# CSS button transition stops playing

Tags: html, css

My CSS transition suddenly stops as shown in the following image

[image]

This only happens on Chrome, on Firefox everything works normally, other than that I cannot test.

The interesting thing is not only that the transition stops for no reason, but is that once I right-click on a button with this class, it works normally for the rest of the browsing session.

The following image is what the button looks like when the working transition ends:

[image]

**HTML and CSS code**

```css
.main-link{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid #53c1f8;
}
.main-link::after {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: none;
  content: "";
  background: #53c1f8;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.75s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}
.main-link:hover::after {
  height: 15em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='main'>
    <div id='content'>
      <div id='main-image'>
        <div id='main-image-intro'>
          <ul id='main-image-cto'>
            <li>
              <a href='subscribe.html' class='main-link'> GET STARTED </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href='subscribe.html' class='main-link'> GIFT IT </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Tested under Ubuntu 15.10:**

- Chromium 47.0.2526.73
- Mozilla Firefox 43.0.4

Comment: Confirmed for Chrome on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: 
I completely changed my answer. Think this should work in any modern browser and be a more save option.

```css
a.button {
    color: black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}
a.button:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    left: 65%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-out;
    transform: skew(45deg) scale(0,1);
    margin-left: -20%;
}
a.button:hover {
    color: white;
}
a.button:hover:after {
    width: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    transform: skew(45deg) scale(400, 1);
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="">Button</a>
```

Comment: What a silly mistake to make, but unfortunately that isn't solving my problem.

Comment: I made the `after` bigger. Is this solving your problem?

Comment: Sadly, still nothing. Peculiarly, the transition has been flipped e.i. it's now at a -45deg angle while on Firefox it still works. Also, it reaches further into the transition.

Comment: Completely changed the answer. This should be a better approach.

Comment: Thank you, this solves the issue of the animation hanging, but now when I remove my mouse the `::after` pseudo class gets removed from view and I can't seem to find the reason, any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know if I got you right, I changed the `width` and the `scale` so that that `:after` will shrink again after removing the mouse. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: It still doesn't appear to shrink. [This](http://i.imgur.com/ckV7ezj.gifv) is what I am getting. I'm looking for something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/PVuzM5p.gifv).

Comment: Sorry, but I can't confirm this. Works for me on Chrome and Firefox, Grows and shrinks as in your example. Have you refreshed the page properly? Which Chrome version are you using?

Comment: Silly, silly me. I had a small syntax error in my code. And I hadn't refreshed this page for the snippet to work. Thank you so much for your help!